# Unable to add grid lines to bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3 and I have constructed [this bar chart](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/47z9bua3/7/).

I would like to add grid lines parallel to *x-axis only*. I saw [this tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-grid-lines-to-d3js-graph.html) and added the code at line # 76.

```
function make_x_axis() {        
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
         .orient("bottom")
         .ticks(5)
}

svg.append("g")         
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(make_x_axis()
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        );
```

However, it didnt help.

What am I missing here?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/47z9bua3/7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want to make lines parallel to x-axis, you should use `make_y_axis` function. And why your lines are not displayed: you have `.tick line { display: none }` you should remove that line.
http://jsfiddle.net/47z9bua3/8/

Comment: Thanks! How do I make the grid lines go into the background of the bars and not over it?

Comment: Is there a way I can show the corresponding y-axis values on the left at the beginning of these grid lines?

Comment: @indieblue sure, add y-axis

Comment: I actually need to do that without showing the y-axis.

Comment: @indieblue add y-axis, display ticks and hide line from that axis by css rule, like you did with grid lines

Comment: I have added the y-axis and set `.tickSize(0)`. The ticks do not seems to be placed same as the grid lines. Also their `value` doesnt match from the `data` array of objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59321/discussion-between-monkeyinsight-and-indie-blue).